# Is having multiple services in constructor and service using repository a good way?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to know If having **multiple services injected** in controllers constructor is wrong? Is there a way to make it more cleaner?

Example (UserController):

```
public function __construct(
        UserService $userService, NewsService $newsService, PaginateService $paginateService, GroupsService $groupsService, HolidaysService $holidaysService,
        CalendarService $calendarService
    )
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->userService = $userService;
        $this->newsService = $newsService;
        $this->paginateService = $paginateService;
        $this->groupsService = $groupsService;
        $this->holidaysService = $holidaysService;
        $this->calendarService = $calendarService;
    }
```

In addition to that I also would like to know if it is good to have service in which I inject the repository - for example: I have UserService and in constrcutor I'm injecting the UserRepository.

Example (UserService):

```
class UserService {

protected $userRepository;

function __construct(UserRespository $userRepository) {
    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
}

public function getUsers() {
    $this->userRepository->getAllUsers();
}

}
```

Comment: One thing that looks wrong to me is that the parent constructor does not take any parameters at all. I would imagine they have the same signature.

Comment: The reason why I am calling BaseController by `parent::__construct();` is that in BaseController I am sharing some variables which I'm using in all controllers.

Comment: What's the difference between the UserService and the user repository ? That to me is a code smell . Check out https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/message-chains

Comment: You should generally aim to have classes that have a single responsibility, so although it's not inherently bad to inject many services, it's a sign that your class has too many responsibilities. Specific to your example, you have a Users controller concerned with `News`, `Groups`, `Holidays` and `Calendars`. That's indicative of a class doing too much.

Comment: Also check out https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/long-parameter-list which basically says your controller is taking on too many responsibilities.

Comment: So it's wrong that my UserController is using these services, because of S in SOLID? Lets say that I have DashboardController which is returning the whole dashboard for user - some calendar, payments data, and other stuff. What then? How I should deal with that?

Comment: @apokryfos for example UserService can create user and in UserRepo I'm only fetching some users data from the db. What do you think about that?

Comment: Then the `UserService` should not fetch user data or the `UserService` should inherit from the `UserRepository` and not wrap around it.

Comment: Okay, so UserService should inherit the repository. Thank you.

Comment: Also, if it would be more readable consider injecting the services each individual controller method requires in the method itself instead of all of them in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like to follow a pattern whereby a controller doesn't have any custom methods. Thus you end up with lots of very thin controllers and ultimately will prevent your above situation (one controller dependant on a large number of services).
so I would break up those services into controller use cases
with generic `resource` methods like `index` `update` `store` `create` `edit` `destroy`.

Another pattern I like to follow is using the `app` helper instead of injecting dependancies into the constructor.
so you can use `app(calendarService::class)->method()`
This results in less code and less stuff to forget.